# Who put together the Hagadah?

Tags: history, passover, passover-seder-hagada, provenance

Who put together the Pesach Hagadah and the seder we have today?

The Mishneh provides some order, but who put together the Hagadah?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haggadah#Authorship).

Comment: What aspects of it? Everything but yachatz and some of the exact formulations in maggid is straight halakha. Kiddish drinking washing dipping asking answering praising blessing drinking washing blessing eating blessing eating eating eating blessing drinking praising blessing drinking. That's all straight halakha.

Comment: @DoubleAA It sounds like he's asking about who compiled the various derashos that compile Maggid from the Mishnah and Mechilta. Whatever you mean RCW, can you edit to clarify?

Comment: @ezra You realize none of those people were part of the Anshei Kneses HaGedolah, right?

Comment: There is no single author - it grew organically and things were added and subtracted over time. Read "The Origins of the Seder" by Baruch Bokser if you want a more thorough critical examination.

Comment: Note that there is significant variation in the Haggadot of the Geonim. Even Rambam's Haggada is significantly shorter than some variations. There is no one Haggada. Therefore, the answer, is that if you are talking about the exact formula of Maggid, that there is basically no answer.

Comment: I believe that the order of the "items" as listed in the "simanim" (e.g. Kadesh, Urchatz, etc.) comes pretty exclusively from the Mishnah Pesachim - at least through Hallel. I don't think Nirtzah is mentioned, there. Almost the entire Maggid is also mentioned in the Mishnah - the text for the questions have changed, of course, over time, but the basis is in the Mishnah. The majority of Maggid cites verses from the Torah, and the text of Rav Gamliel, etc. is also in the Mishnah. That leaves very few other paragraphs left that were later add ins.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Menachem Mendel Kasher, says that part of it was compiled by the Anshei Knesses Hagedola.
The Avudraham says that there were originally two versions one by Rav and Shmuel and one by Abaye and Rava.
Rav Amram Gaon wrote some and so did Rav Saadiah Gaon.
The Ma Nishtana is from a Mishna in Pesachim. Much of the Haggadah is from the Mishna, Gemara, and Midrashim.

Comment: If you [edit] in where R' Kasher and Avudraham wrote these things, how you know the mentioned _g'onim_ wrote parts, and how you know parts are from _mishnayos_, _g'mara_, and _midrashim_, that'd improve your answer quality enormously.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Maggid section, or basically the section of the Haggadah that precedes the meal, refer to [this excellent article](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/The_Origin_of_the_Haggadah.pdf). It's mainly in Hebrew, and it would defeat the purpose for me to translate it.

In short, much of it comes from the Mishnah, and parts of it from various Siddurim such as Rav AMram Ga'on. Rav Sa'adiah Gaon, and some others. You'll also find a list of sources supporting th econcept of the mitzvah of telling the story of the Exodus.